# How to show vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I show these vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R^2}$ . If they are not, what would be the dependency relationship?

$(2,-1), (3,2), (0,1)$? Wouldn't they be linearly dependent?

If I try to represent them as a linear combination, I get two equations and three unknowns, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any three vectors in a 2-dimensional space must be linearly dependent.

A common way to show that $n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are linearly independent is to make an $n$-by-$n$ matrix from the vectors and calculate the determinant. If the determinant is non-zero, the vectors are independent.

If the number of vectors is greater than the dimension of the vector space, the vectors must be linearly dependent. No calculation is needed. One way to find the dependency relationship is to place the vectors in a matrix augmented with the identity matrix. The reduced row echelon form will show the relationship in the augmented part, I believe.

If the number of vectors is less than the dimension of the vector space, you can make a matrix of the vectors, with each line being a row vector. Find the reduced row echelon form of the matrix. If any row becomes zero, the vectors are dependent. Otherwise, they are independent.

These are just common methods. Other methods also exist.

Comment: Yes, but you can't make an nxn matrix in this case because two equations and 3 unknowns, so the coefficient matrix would be 2x3, which means they're automatically linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes. If the number of vectors is greater than the dimension of the vector space, they must be linearly dependent.

Comment: Also, what would be the dependency relationship?

Comment: I wish they had teachers like you at my high school! It seems that you know what you're doing beyond the math you have to teach, yes? The teachers at my high school don't really "know math"; they just stare at 20-year-old notes and put it on the board. It's as if they've only memorized the bare minimum required to just teach the basics.

Comment: @MathStackExchange: I am a high school math teacher and I have taught matrices. In your situation you may want to pick up a good book on the subject and read it. Your class textbook may well be a good book: check into it. As a last resort, you could always transfer into my school!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the relation $c_1(2,-1)+c_2(3,2)+c_3(0,1)=0$

We get the following equations:

$1.2c_1+3c_2=0$

$2.-c_1+2c_2+c_3=0$

Eliminating $c_1$ we get $c_2+2c_3=0$ i.e.$c_2=-2c_3$

Substituting in the $1^{st}$ equation $c_1=3c_3$

Putting $c_3=k$ where $k \in \mathbb R$ we get $c_1=3k,c_2=-2k$ as the required relation

Answer (score 0):

Any three vectors in two-space are linearly dependent.  We need to find $a,b$ and $c$ such that $a(2,-1)+b(3,2)+c(0,1)=(0,0)$.  This equation consists of the two equations $2a+3b=0$ and $-a+2b+c=0$.  We can proceed by eliminating $a$: add the first equation to twice the second equation, and we get $7b+2c=0$.  Take $c=-7$ and solve to get $b=2$. Substituting into the first equation gives $a=-3$.  Thus, we get the linear dependency relationship $-3(2,-1)+2(3,2)+(-7)(0,1)=(0,0)$.

Comment: That way we get a nice round number when we solve for $b$. The equation is $7b+2c=0$.  Since when we solve for $b$ we need to divide by its coefficient 7, take $c$ to be a multiple of 7 so that there are no fractions. Other solutions are possible and you can pick $c$ to be any nonzero value.

Comment: So these are arbitrary?

Comment: yes, but they can't all be zero.

Comment: Oh, why do they need to be nonzero? I mean, I can see that they need to be, but why?

Comment: check the definition of linear dependency.  A set of vectors is linearly dependent if there exist scalars, not all zero, such that...